# Автоматическое масштабирование TabControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

Доброго времени суток всем! Как можно сделать масштабирование TabControl при растягивании окна приложения или сворачивания/разворачивания? На данный момент масштабируется только по горизонтали. По вертикали стоит стандартный размер(Авто 34).

```
<Window x:Class="Client.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <TabControl  x:Name="mainTab" Margin="0" Height="319">
            <TabControl.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </TabControl.Effect>
            <TabItem  x:Name="smartphonesTab">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="3">Конвертер валют</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>

            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="wetherTab">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="3">Погода</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem x:Name="notesTab">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="3">Заметки</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>

        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="personList" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Скриншот окна при запуске]
[image: Растянутое окно]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    <TabControl  x:Name="mainTab" 
                 Margin="0" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                 Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                 AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

Теперь будет подстраиваться под высоту окна!

Comment: без свойства Height значение в окошке свойствах Авто(34).

Comment: @JDo уберите и запустите проект, я думаю Вы сильно удивитесь!

Comment: Нет, я не смог удивиться... Полоска в 34 пикселя. ![Картинка](https://habrastorage.org/web/e6f/e54/a8e/e6fe54a8e0024a4f90865ab252254263.png).

Comment: @JDo понял что Вам необходимо, изменил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое! То что нужно!

Comment: Не понимаю. Разве он сам по себе не масштабируется? Просто автор запихал его в StackPanel и указал высоту, вот авто и не работает.

Comment: Проще отказаться от `StackPanel`

Comment: Спасибо. Да, вы правы. Это контейнер StackPanel. Не углядел и обернул им.

Answer (score 1):

Как советовали в камментах, вот такой вариант более подходит, как мне кажется.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>  
        <TabControl  x:Name="mainTab" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <TabControl.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </TabControl.Effect>
            <TabItem  x:Name="smartphonesTab">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="3">Конвертер валют</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>

            </TabItem>
            <TabItem x:Name="wetherTab">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="3">Погода</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>

            <TabItem x:Name="notesTab">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Margin="3">Заметки</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>    
    <ListBox x:Name="personList" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```